# How do I validate the term title in hook_taxonomy_term_presave()?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, hooks

I rendered the form to create a taxonomy term via the [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) module.

Is there a way to validate the values submitted in that form using `hook_taxonomy_term_presave()` or another hook?
I tried with `hook_form_alter()`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you should be looking at hook_form_FORM_ID_alter instead of hook_taxonomy_term_presave for validating the term title before saving.

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
**/
function mymodule_form_taxonomy_form_term_alter(&$form,  &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Check for tags bundle.
  if($form['#bundle'] == 'tags') {
    // Apply custom validator.
    $form['#validate'][] = '_mymodule_custom_term_validator';
  }
}
```

My custom validator.

```
/**
 * My custom validator for tags.
 **/
function _mymodule_custom_term_validtor() {
  // Check for term name is test.
  if(form_state['values']['name'] == 'test') {
    form_set_error('name', 'Title cannot be "test"');
  }
}
```

Comment: I rendered taxonomy add term form via "Inline Entity Form" module and here form_alter fails when it comes to validation.

Any other way if hook_entity_presave can't do this?

Answer (score 0):

`hook_taxonomy_term_presave()` is not thought for validating what submitted in a form. In fact, it doesn't have any way to stop Drupal from saving the taxonomy term, nor does it allow users to correct the wrongly submitted value. That is what a validation handler does.

In this case, since the form to create a taxonomy term is added with the *Inline Entity Form* module, the hook to implement is [`hook_inline_entity_form_entity_form_alter()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/inline_entity_form/-/blob/7.x-1.x/inline_entity_form.api.php#L16).

```php
function mymodule_inline_entity_form_entity_form_alter(&$entity_form, &$form_state) {
  if ($entity_form['#entity_type'] == 'taxonomy_term') {
    // Add the form validation handler.
  }
}
```

The form elements are added by [`TaxonomyTermInlineEntityFormController::entityForm()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/inline_entity_form/-/blob/7.x-1.x/includes/taxonomy_term.inline_entity_form.inc#L54) which uses the following code.

```php
$entity_form['name'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Name'),
  '#default_value' => $term->name,
  '#maxlength' => 255,
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#weight' => !empty($extra_fields['name']) ? $extra_fields['name']['weight'] : -5,
);
$entity_form['description'] = array(
  '#type' => 'text_format',
  '#title' => t('Description'),
  '#default_value' => $term->description,
  '#format' => $term->format,
  '#weight' => !empty($extra_fields['description']) ? $extra_fields['description']['weight'] : -4,
);

$langcode = entity_language('taxonomy_term', $term);
field_attach_form('taxonomy_term', $term, $entity_form, $form_state, $langcode);
```

Comment: I rendered taxonomy add term form via "Inline Entity Form" module and here form_alter fails when it comes to validation.

Any other way if hook_entity_presave can't do this?

Comment: A validation handler is the only way.